# Wcf service posting data IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf, web-services

I am new on web service. I am trying to send some parameters to web service.

Here is the my service link http://quizmedb.somee.com/Service.svc?wsdl

And i have this method `bool signUp(string username, string name, string surname, string mail, string pass)` in my service.

I used this code for posting my data.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                         "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope \n"
                         "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
                         "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n"
                         "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                         "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                         "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
                         "<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                         "<signUp xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><username>%@</username><name>%@</name><surname>%@</surname><mail>%@</mail><pass>%@</pass>"
                         "</signUp> \n"
                         "</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                         "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>",@"RandomName",nameTextField.text,surnameTextField.text,emailTextField.text,passTextField.text];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://quizmedb.somee.com/Service.svc?wsdl"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/Service/signUp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(theConnection) {
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse           *)response{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);


 NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"result : %@",strData);

}
```

But i can't get any string from service. What is my mistake , i couldn't find.
 Can you help me?
 Thanks for your answer and interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error while executing this code?

By the way, In my opinion your soap action is not correct,

```
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/Service/signUp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
```

As per the wsdl, it should be,

```
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService/signUp" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
```

Hope it would resolve your issue. :D

I tried your wsdl from soap ui, your request message is not forming properly. That's why it's returning nothing.
Can you change your request message format like this in your code:

```
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
             <soapenv:Body>
                    <tem:signUp>
                        <tem:username>%@</tem:username>
                        <tem:ad>%@</tem:ad>
                        <tem:soyad>%@</tem:soyad>
                        <tem:mail>%@</tem:mail>
                        <tem:pass>%@</tem:pass>
                    </tem:signUp>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

or for testing,You can use following request message also

```
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
             <soapenv:Body>
                    <tem:signUp>
                   </tem:signUp>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

It will return you following response.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
      <signUpResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <signUpResult>true</signUpResult>
      </signUpResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Nope i don't get any error, just Nothing is returning to me from web service, i also tried your answer but it doesn't work.I wonder, my SoapMessage or my URL can be wrong?

Comment: Can you try debugging your code. And see whether you are sending proper soap message before calling your url. I have tried your wsdl in soapui. I noticed slight difference in scemas other than that it looked fine. Ill let you know later.

Comment: my soapMessage like that; soapMessage = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
<signUp xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><username>asd</username><name>asd</name><surname>asd</surname><mail>asd</mail><pass>asd</pass></signUp> 
</SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: And also webData = <> is coming like that.                         DONE. Received Bytes: 0
result :

Comment: i didn't understand what i am doing wrong...@" <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n""<soapenv:Header/>"
     "<soapenv:Body>"
     "<tem:signUp>"
     "<tem:username>%@</tem:username>"
     "<tem:ad>%@</tem:ad>"
     "<tem:soyad>%@</tem:soyad>"
     "<tem:mail>%@</tem:mail>"
     "<tem:pass>%@</tem:pass>"
     "</tem:signUp>"
     "</soapenv:Body>"
     "</soapenv:Envelope>",@"asd",@"asd",@"asd",@"asd",@"asd"

Comment: I wrote like this,is this Correct? Maybe i can make a mistake on quotes.

Comment: Or if it is possible can you give me your e-mail, i can share with you.

Comment: Actually i am not familiar with this language's syntax so i won't be able to tell you what are you doing wrong. Though, ill try to figure it out on Monday.If you frequently use webservices, download soapui on your machine and generate a request message from there and then try to make your request message in code.It will be more easy for you. One more thing , can't you define soapmessage as simple string , why are you changing line using /n. It should also work without that, i guess.

Comment: I guess I did :), Respose Data :<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><signUpResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">            <signUpResult>true</signUpResult></signUpResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>  and i changed "\n" and i added [webData setLength:0]; and [webData appendData:data]; inside of the methods. Thank you for your answer and interest.